# Submit form after success return after ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I validate my form with both client and sever side scripting. First I validate it with jQuery then it goes to php validation and if it returns success or something like that I want to submit the form but some how the condition does not work. However in html `err_msg` I get success text but its not working.

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function () {
        var name = $na('#inf_field_FirstName').val();
        var password = $na('#inf_field_Password').val();
        var cpass = $na('#cpass').val();
        var email = $na('#inf_field_Email').val();
        var age = $na('#inf_custom_Age').val();
        $na.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<?php bloginfo('
            template_url ')?>/user_create.php',
            data: 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&password=' + password + '&cpass=' + cpass + '&age=' + age,
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                jQuery('.err_msg').html(result);
                if (jQuery('.err_msg').html == 'sucess') {
                    jQuery("#inform").submit();
                } else {
                    alert('error');
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Why validate server-side and _then_ submit? Why not just send the data, and have the server-side code return an error or perform an update?

Comment: because client side validation does not check user existence in database.

Comment: Try `jQuery("#inform")[0].submit();`

Comment: @vishal I understand why you need to validate on the server-side. I don't understand why you need to make one server call to validate and another to send the same data.

Comment: because i have a form which create user in wordpress and sends data to remote site using submit form at a same time

Comment: @jawant i tried to submit form jQuery("#inform")[0].submit() but not working

Answer (score 0):

use `jQuery("#inform")[0].submit();`

otherwise, if u have submit button in your form just trigger that button

```
jQuery("#submit_btn_id").trigger('click')
```